# How to implement Websocket (RFC 6455) in my server?

Tags: php, websocket

I have searched it in Google and here in stackoverflow there are some questions about it.
The problem is that many of them are old, so I guess that they use older and deprecated protocols instead of RFC 6455. I don't know if it is because of that or if I am doing something wrong, but when I try it it doesn't work.

So...

1. If I understand well, I can implement Websockets with aproppiate client (Javascript) and server (PHP) code, without needing to configure my Apache server. I am right?
2. Why the hell all examples I have found require me to go to command line and do

   php -q C:\path\to\file\Websocket\Server.php
3. In the implementations I have found, there are a default server and port. Must I change them to the server (localhost) and port which I use for normal webpages? Or should I tell my server to listen to another port and use it for websocket communication?
4. Where can I find a good PHP implementation of Websockets (RFC 6455)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Yes, that is correct.
2. Because the Websocket server doesn't use your web daemon to serve data.  In this case, you're writing a server daemon completely in PHP.
3. You need to choose a port, since you're not using the web daemon to serve your websockets.  Any port that's not in use will do.
4. Try [Ratchet](http://packagist.org/packages/cboden/Ratchet) (main site [here](http://socketo.me/)).  We've been using the dev-master branch for a couple months in production now and we haven't had any problems.  It's the only solution we found that out of the box will work with both Firefox clients and iPhones.

Comment: Thanks! It seems it didn't work because I was using the same port for serving webpages and websockets. I didn't understant how Ratchet works nor configure it, but https://github.com/lemmingzshadow/php-websocket/ worked. Now I will modify things and understand well how it works, in order to implement it in my server.

Comment: @Oriol: Just FYI, the library you linked appears to only do HyBi 10 and 13, not RFC 6455.  I was assuming that you asked specifically about RFC 6455 for a reason.  =)

Comment: I wanted RFC 6455 because it's the last version, so I guess it's the safest and best, and supported by the last browsers. But I thought that HyBi 13 is the same as RFC 6455, was I wrong?

Comment: @Oriol: Check this link for the differences between the two - http://tools.ietf.org/rfcdiff?url1=draft-ietf-hybi-thewebsocketprotocol-13.txt&url2=rfc6455.txt The main thing to notice is that 13 was still a draft (and there were a few more revisions before RFC6455 was settled).  Functionally, I'm not sure of the differences.

Comment: But I don't understand why http://tools.ietf.org/html/draft-ietf-hybi-thewebsocketprotocol-13#page-64 says that Websocket version 13 is hybi 13, but http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc6455#page-63 says that version 13 is RFC 6455.

Comment: @Oriol: Shoot, now I can't find the list that put RFC6455 as version 17.  It's confusing, I agree.  Ultimately, if it works for your purposes, I don't think it matters what version you use.  ;)  Good luck with your project!

Comment: Yes, I think I will try that implementation, regardless v13 refers to hybi 13 or RFC6455, as long as it works. Thanks!